# Как заставить класс одного js работать внутри var другого js

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте, уважаемые эксперты! Помогите, пожалуйста, в решении, я уверен очень простого для Вас, вопроса.

1. Есть текстовое поле, в котором слева значок добавления. При нажатии добавляется ниже следующее текстовое поле уже со значком удалить и т.д. Для этого используется первый js с таким кодом.

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(){
       var maxField = 10; //Input fields increment limitation
       var addButton = $('.add_button'); //Add button selector
       var wrapper = $('.field_wrapper'); //Input field wrapper
       var fieldHTML = '<input type="text" name="" class="data_picker" value="" />'; //New input field html
       var x = 1; //Initial field counter is 1
       $(addButton).click(function(){ //Once add button is clicked
           if(x < maxField){ //Check maximum number of input fields
               x++; //Increment field counter
               $(wrapper).append(fieldHTML); // Add field html
           }
       });
       $(wrapper).on('click', '.remove_button', function(e){ //Once remove button is clicked
           e.preventDefault();
           $(this).parent('div').remove(); //Remove field html
           x--; //Decrement field counter
       });
   });
   ```
2. Внутри var fieldHTML инпут с классом data_picker. Это класс, который используется следующим js для ввода времени. Вот код.

   ```
   $(function(){
       $('.data_picker').timepicker().each(function(i){
           eval($(this).text());
       });
   });
   ```

Вопрос состоит в том, что если использовать просто класс *.time_picker* в обычном html всё отлично работает. Но, когда помещаю его в js, который добавляет поля, он не работает. Пожалуйста, подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы js второй работал при добавлении полей. Очень нужна ваша помощь. Заранее огромное спасибо.

Comment: так какой код не работает-то?

Comment: Здравствуйте. По отдельности оба работают. Но мне нужно поместить второй в первый. Чтобы при добавлении поля работал второй код, который сейчас не хочет работать.

Comment: Тогда в чем заключается вопрос? :-)

Comment: Поправил сверху. Извиняюсь впервые задаю вопрос тут.

Comment: Хотя да, очевидная проблема с тем, что нужно просто вызывать _timepicker()_ **после** добавления элемента

Comment: Пожалуйста, подскажите, как правильно сделать :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решается проблема вызовом *timepicker()* - перед добавлением

```
$(addButton).click(function(){ //Once add button is clicked
    if(x < maxField){ //Check maximum number of input fields
        x++; //Increment field counter
        var f = $(fieldHTML).timepicker().each(function(i){
            eval($(this).text());
        });
        $(wrapper).append(f); // Add field html
    }
});
```

либо после

```
$(addButton).click(function(){ //Once add button is clicked
    if(x < maxField){ //Check maximum number of input fields
        x++; //Increment field counter
        var f = $(fieldHTML);
        $(wrapper).append(f); // Add field html
        f.timepicker().each(function(i){
            eval($(this).text());
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: Сейчас исправил первый код по Вашим наставлениям. Если правильно понял. Посмотрите, пожалуйста. Но сейчас перестала добавляться новая строка.

Comment: @Mesh, какая именно строка перестала добавляться? свой ответ в данном случае стоит удалить, так как он не является ответом и код в крайнем случае можно добавить в сам вопрос отредактировав его, нажимая кнопку _править_ под вопросом

Comment: Понял. Извините. Первый  js служит для добавления этих самых полей. Слева значок плюс нажимаю на него и добавляется ниже поле. В этом поле я хочу чтобы использовался второй js с классом time_picker. То есть я добавляю поле и внутри каждого поля должен использоваться time_picker. Сейчас первый js перестал добавлять поля.

Comment: @Mesh, что-то ты не договариваешь: в приведенном коде _нет ни одного упоминания_ класса *time_picker*. и единственное что поменялось, что теперь инициализация происходит для каждого инпута отдельно при добавлении

Comment: <input type="text" name="" class="data_picker" value="" />

Comment: @Mesh, покажи в этом куске разметки класс **time_picker**

Comment: если так вставляю в html, всё работает. Если помещаю внутрь первого js внутри var, то не работает.

Comment: @Mesh, смотри ошибки в консоли браузера. И еще не понятно: в чем смысл `each(function(i){
            eval($(this).text());
        })`?

Comment: @Mesh, делай [mcve] в котором будет и разметка и необходимый js, Добавить сниппет ты можешь при редактировании вопроса нажав кнопку "добавить пример кода" с иконкой `<>`

Comment: Понял. Да, действительно. Была ошибка стояла data вместо time. Изменил. Но ничего не изменилось. Спасибо большое, что помогаете. Покажу наглядно. 3-ий тугл сверху http://mesh.dp.ua/screen/

Comment: Вся проблема в том, что mazilla и ie не поддерживают type="time". Если бы такой проблемы не было я бы и не замарачивался. Приходится придумывать велосипед.

Comment: @Mesh, смотри ошибки в консоли: _(index):101 Uncaught ReferenceError: sel_iff2 is not defined_